# How to simulate a corrupt SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Part of the startup routine in my application validates its SQLite databases by using the `PRAGMA integrity_check;` API.  I'm looking for a way to legitimately corrupt an SQLite database so that this "integrity check" will fail.

I've tried messing with the database file in a text editor, but this causes a type of corruption that is caught when opening the database, much earlier than my call to "integrity check".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PRAGMA writable_schema](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_writable_schema) allows you to change the database schema behind SQLite's back, and thus to violate constraints:

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
> CREATE TABLE t(x);
> CREATE INDEX tx ON t(x);
> INSERT INTO t VALUES (1), (1);
> PRAGMA writable_schema = 1;
> UPDATE sqlite_master
>   SET sql = 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tx ON t(x)'
>   WHERE type = 'index' AND name = 'tx';
> .quit
$ sqlite3 test.db   # reload
> PRAGMA integrity_check;
non-unique entry in index tx
```